# Hamilton equations-Symplectic scheme

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, hamiltonian-mechanics

We know that $\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$ and $\dot{p} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}$, and we also know the values $Q$ and $P$ respectively of $q$ and $p$ at a later time step $\Delta t$. How could we prove that the quantities
$$
\begin{align}
Q &= q + {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q,p),\\
P &= p - {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(q,p)
\end{align}
$$
are not symplectic, while
$$
\begin{align}
Q &= q - {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q,p),\\
P &= p + {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial Q}(Q,p) 
\end{align}
$$
are symplectic?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. How can you say both that $Q,P$ are $q,p$ at a later time step and also that they are given by the equations above? Surely if we wait for some amount of time $\Delta t$, the location of $Q,P$ will usually be a nonlinear function of the time step $\Delta t$. Are you asking that this holds up to higher order terms in $\Delta t$? If so, you can't choose which of the two expressions for $Q,P$ you get to use.

Comment: Assuming that you are asking that $Q,P$ be computed using a linear approximation, linear in $\Delta t$, then clearly both are symplectic, since one is the flow of $H$ and the other the flow of $-H$.

Comment: @BenMcKay I am sorry to confuse you! This is supposed to be a transformation! And I want to know if it is symplectic or not

Comment: @BenMcKay also the difference is that the second hamiltonian does not depend on q but Q

Comment: Maybe I should try again to clarify my confusion. In your first sentence, you define $Q,P$ to be the result of applying a Hamiltonian flow to some $q,p$. In your second sentence, you first define $Q,P$ to be certain functions of $q,p$ and $\Delta t$. In the second clause of the second sentence, you write down two equations involving variables called $Q,P$. Are the $Q,P$ in the first sentence intended to equal those in the second sentence, 1st clause? What about the second sentence second clause?

Comment: ... If so, how would we know that these $Q,P$ from the second sentence, first or second clause, are equal to those in the first sentence, as their definition appears to be completely unrelated?

Comment: @BenMcKay The sets of equations define different numerical integrators: in the first case $(q_{i+1}, p_{i+1})$ directly in terms of $(q_i, p_i)$, and in the second case $q_{i+1}$ in terms of $(q_i,p_i)$, and $p_{i+1}$ in terms of $(q_{i+1},p_i)$. Anyway, the question seems to be more suited for [Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RicardoBuring i trasnfered this question to math.stack exchange! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052524/hamilton-equations-symplectic-scheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that your question is about why the symplectic Euler method is symplectic, while the explicit Euler method is not.

The point is that for a Hamiltonian of the form $H(p,q)=T(p)+V(q)$, the symplectic Euler method can be seen as the composition of the two steps
\begin{align*}
\tilde{q} &= q_i+T'(p_i)\,\Delta t\\
\tilde{p} &= p_i
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
q_{i+1} &= \tilde{q}\\
p_{i+1} &= \tilde{p}-V'(\tilde{q})\,\Delta t
\end{align*}
whose Jacobians are
$$
\frac{\partial(\tilde{q},\tilde{p})}{\partial(q_i,p_i)}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&T''(p_i)\,\Delta t\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)
~~~~~\text{ and }~~~~~
\frac{\partial(q_{i+1},p_{i+1})}{\partial(\tilde{q},\tilde{p})}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ -V''(\tilde{q})\,\Delta t&1\end{array}\right)
$$
respectively. Since both determinants are identically one, it is readily seen that the symplectic Euler step exactly preserves the phase space volume $dq\wedge dp$.

For the explicit Euler method, no such intermediate step exists, and the Jacobian has a determinant that is not exactly equal to one, hence the phasespace volume is not exactly preserved by the numerical integration.